# Px to Dp conversion in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am into a situation where I need to set the width of the TextView programatically to 50 .
I need to convert this 50 to dp as I did not find any provision to set the width as dp programatically. Can any one help me how do we convert pixels to dps in Android.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a couple of utility methods I wrote ages ago, which seem to come in handy very often:

```
/**
 * Converts pixel to dip.
 * 
 * @param pixel
 *            that should be converted.
 * @return the converted rounded dip.
 */
private int pixelToDip(int pixel) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = mContext.getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics();
    return (int) ((pixel / displayMetrics.density) + 0.5);
}

/**
 * Converts dip to pixel.
 * 
 * @param dip
 *            that should be converted.
 * @return the converted rounded pixel.
 */
private int dipToPixel(int dip) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = mContext.getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics();
    return (int) ((dip * displayMetrics.density) + 0.5);
}
```

You'll either have to run this in a subclass of Context, or have it get a Context from somewhere. I pass in a Context in my Utility class constructor and store it in `mContext`.

Comment: why do you return the floored dip ?

Comment: @blackbelt Two things. My documentation appears to be wrong. The +0.5 should round it to the closest next integer value, not floor it. Secondly, Having half a pixel or half a dp doesn't make much sense when you're drawing stuff :P

Comment: to me seems something like the Ceil of the value not the floor.

Comment: @blackbelt Yep. See my previous comment. I've updated my answer to reflect the correct info. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: I agree with you +1 from me

Comment: do we need to pass pixel val as integer only or can we pass float val too ?

Comment: @Android_programmer_office In my method I pass it as an integer. You can always pass it in as a float, but once again, I don't see where you'd be getting a fraction of a pixel from, and how you would draw it.